# How to modify SharePoint 2016 Browse / Page Bar?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, branding

I added a banner image to the Suite Nav Bar using $webapp.suitenavbrandinglogourl and manipulated height and width using .o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2. However, the height spills into the browse and page bar. Please See the image below.  How can I modify browse / page bar?  Can this be done with css?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the height of the div#suiteBatTop. As the below picture shows, the default height is 50px. Below is my demo CSS style for your reference:

```
<style>
div#suiteBarTop{
height:70px !important;
}

</style>
```

[image]